# R Shiny - Downloading a PDF Report Error

Tags: r, pdf, shiny, latex, knitr

The issue is weird in the sense that I *can* recreate the exact same PDF report with knitr outside of the Shiny app. The code does work if I use HTML as output format. I have the latest version from [MikTex](https://miktex.org/download)

See code below:

```
output$report <- downloadHandler(
  filename = paste(Sys.Date(), "GebiedsRapportage.html"),

  content = function(file) {

    #tempReport <- file.path(tempdir(), "report_html.Rmd")
    tempReport <- file.path(tempdir(), "report_pdf.Rmd")

    #file.copy("report_html.Rmd", tempReport, overwrite = TRUE)
    file.copy("report_pdf.Rmd", tempReport, overwrite = TRUE)

    rmarkdown::render(tempReport, output_file = file)
  }
)
```

So, using the #HTML functions works fine, but the PDF function gives me the following error:

```
Warning: running command '"pdflatex" -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode "file2e8466131256.tex"' had status 1
Warning: Error in : Failed to compile file2e8466131256.tex.
Stack trace (innermost first):
    58: show_latex_error
    57: on_error
    56: system2_quiet
    55: run_engine
    54: latexmk_emu
    53: tinytex::latexmk
    52: latexmk
    51: rmarkdown::render
    50: download$func [server/server_data_analysis.R#311]
     1: runApp
Error : Failed to compile file2e8466131256.tex.
```

While knitting the file itself without interacting with Shiny generates a PDF perfectly fine.

Anyone encountered the same issue?

Comment: What does the `.log` say? And does it work without copying the document into a temporary folder?

Comment: There does not seem to be a difference when I remove the copying part of the code. The error remains the same. Unsure what you mean with the .log. Putting a breakpoint at the downloadHandler function also doesn't give additional insights..

Comment: Well when pdflatex compiles a tex file, there will also be a log file. You could check in there for errors (which is not very likely). In any case upgrade the rmarkdown package if you have not done that already.